resizing two arrays to be used in a DataFrame
I'm trying to create a pandas DataFrame from a dictionary. We know that to do so, all the dictionary elements must be of the same dimension. The dictionary is composed of two ndarrays; one with the shape of (325,) and the other one with the shape of (325,1). I'm looking for a way to reshape either one of them so that the DataFrame can be created. Thanks in advance.
When I run the code the following error is encountered:
    raise ValueError("Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional")
ValueError: Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional

The following picture shows the dictionary details:


You might create DataFrame from single 2D numpy.array, I would flatten 2D array, then stack them, then transpose, then make DataFrame. Simplified example
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3])  # shape (3,)
arr2 = np.array([[4],[5],[6]])  # shape (3,1)
arr_together = np.vstack([arr1, arr2.flatten()])  # shape (2,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr_together.T, columns=["col1","col2"])
print(df)

gives output
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6

Observe that values in col1 are from arr1, whilst values in col2 are from arr2.
